# Problems with Dell B2360dn printer on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, printing, dell

I am having trouble with my Dell B2360dn laser printer since the operating system upgrade. I cannot find drivers for it.

The printer is connected and can print some jobs, but at the moment I cannot print multiple copies of anything and when I print multiple page documents I cannot turn duplex off. It is the busiest time of the year for me and it is driving me crazy.

Does anyone know a solution that would allow me to keep using the printer. I am thinking of rolling back the Ubuntu upgrade, but that seems a drastic and unreliable solution for it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never:

Driver files available at:
https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/dell-b2360dn/drivers

The goal is to install the PPD file that matches your installation, so .deb is at the end. Note there are a bunch of .deb, .rpm, and .tar.gz files in here and a few different packages. The PPD files in the .deb (or, if you want to move them manually, in the .tar.gz) are what you want.